# Assembly Language Program - fatal error A1010

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, x86, masm, irvine32

Here is the assignment:

Write a "menu-driven" program that reads a paragraph from the keyboard and processes it in the following fashion:

Count the number of characters in the paragraph,
Count the number of words,
Count the number of letters that are the same as the third letter of your last name,
Count the number of capital letters.

Terminate the paragraph with special character :

If your last name begins with  A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H terminate the paragraph with #,

If your last name begins with  I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P  terminate the paragraph with %,

If your last name begins with  R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z terminate the paragraph with &,

For this exercise you are required to use subroutines. Read the paragraph in the main procedure;

Process paragraph in subroutines (separate procedure  for each count).

**Here is my code, I am getting an A1010 error(unmatched block nesting: main) on the last line and I can't figure out why, please help. I'm using Visual Studio 2015:**

```
include Irvine32.inc

displayMSG MACRO MSG            

      MOV      AH, 09H

      LEA      DX, MSG

      INT      21H

      ENDM

.DATA

      para     DB 100 , ? , 100 DUP('$')

;messages for menu     

      mes1     DB 0AH, 0DH, 'MENU $'

      mes21    DB 0AH, 0DH, '1.COUNT CHARACTERS $'

      mes22    DB 0AH, 0DH, '2.COUNT WORDS $'

      mes23    DB 0AH, 0DH, '3.COUNT CAPITAL LETTERS $'

      mes24    DB 0AH, 0DH, '4.COUNT THIRD LETTER $'

      mes25    DB 0AH, 0DH, '5.EXIT $'

      mes3     DB 0AH, 0DH, 'ENTER YOUR CHOICE : $'

      mes4     DB 0AH, 0DH, 'WRONG CHOICE $'

      mes5     DB 0AH, 0DH, 'ENTER THE PARAGRAPH : $'     

      mes6     DB 0AH, 0DH, 'NUMBER OF CHARACTERS IS : $'

      mes7     DB 0AH, 0DH, 'NUMBER OF WORDS $'

      mes8     DB 0AH, 0DH, 'NUMBER OF CAPITAL LETTERS $'

      mes9 DB 0AH, 0DH, 'NUMBER OF THIRD LETTER $'

.CODE

main PROC

 start:  

      mov           ax, @data   

      mov           ds, ax

      mov           es, ax

      displayMSG    mes5 ;PROMPT THE USER TO ENTER A PARAGRAPH

      mov ah, 0ah     ; Accept PARAGRAPH

      lea dx, para

      int 21h

 ;DISPLAY MENU TO THE USER

 menu :

      displayMSG           mes1    

      displayMSG           mes21

      displayMSG           mes22

      displayMSG           mes23

      displayMSG           mes24

      displayMSG           mes25

      displayMSG           mes3     ; accept choice

      mov       ah, 01h

      int       21h

      mov       bl, al     ; userChoice BL       

      cmp       bl, 31h     ; if userChoice=1

      je        FINDCHAR          ; Find NUMBER OF CHARACTERS IN THE STRING



      cmp bl, 32h     ; if userChoice=2

      je FINDWORDS         ; FIND NUMBER OF WORDS

      cmp      bl, 33h     ; if userChoice=3

      je        FINDCAPITAL          ; FIND NUMBER OF CAPITAL LETTERS

      cmp      bl, 34h     ; if userChoice=4

      je        FINDLETTER                          

      cmp     bl, 35h     ; if userChoice=5

      je      L1     ; exit

      displayMSG           mes4     ; Wrong Choice

      jmp     menu

 FINDCHAR:    

      call FINDCHARPROC

      jmp menu

 FINDWORDS :    

      call FINDWORDSPROC

      jmp menu

 FINDCAPITAL:    

      call FINDCAPITALSPROC

      jmp menu

 FINDLETTER :    

      call FINDTHIRDPROC

      jmp menu

 L1: 
      end start
      exit

exit
main ENDP  

;procedure THAT FINDS NUMBER OF CHARACTERS

FINDCHARPROC proc 

      displayMSG    mes6

      mov dl, para+1     ; NUMBER OF CHARACTERS IN THE PARAGRAPH

      or   dl, 30h

      mov ah, 02h          ; DISPLAY THE CHARACTERS COUNT                         

      int 21h

      ret

FINDCHARPROC ENDP

;find number of WORDS in the paragraph

FINDWORDSPROC   proc    

      mov dl,00h

      mov       ch, 00h                     

      lea       esi, para+2        

      mov       cl, para+1   

      mov bl,20h        ;ASCII value of space

loopAn:

      dec cl

      cmp       cl, 00h

      je        printWordCount

      cmp bl, [esi] ;check if character is space

      je   incWordCnt        

      inc esi      

      jne      loopAn

incWordCnt:

      inc dl

      inc esi

      jmp loopAn

printWordCount:

      displayMSG    mes7

      or   dl,30h

      mov ah,02h

      int 21h

      ret      

FINDWORDSPROC ENDP

;find number of CAPITAL letters in the paragraph

FINDCAPITALSPROC   proc     

      mov dl,00h

      mov       ch, 00h                     

      lea       esi, para+2     ; USER INPUTTED PARAGRAPH  

      mov       cl, para+1         

loopAgn:

      dec cl

      cmp       cl, 00h

      je        printcapitalCount

      mov al, byte ptr[esi]

      cmp al,"A"    ;check if character is capital

      jb   nextChar

      cmp al,"Z"    ;check if character is capital

      ja   nextChar   

      inc esi

      inc dl       

      jne      loopAgn

nextChar:

      inc esi

      jmp loopAgn

printcapitalCount :

      displayMSG    mes8

      or   dl,30h

      mov ah,02h

      int 21h

      ret      

FINDCAPITALSPROC ENDP

;count the number of third letter present in the paragraph

FINDTHIRDPROC   proc     

      mov dl,00h

      mov       ch, 00h                     

      lea       esi, para+2     ; DESTINATION STRING     

      mov       cl, para+1

      call      ReadChar   ;get THIRD letter of your name    

loopTemp:

      dec cl

      cmp       cl, 00h

      je        printCount

      cmp al, [esi] ;check if character is your third letter

      je   incCnt     

      inc esi      

      jne      loopTemp

incCnt:

      inc dl

      inc esi

      jmp loopTemp

printCount :

      displayMSG    mes9

      or   dl,30h

      mov ah,02h

      int 21h

      ret      

FINDTHIRDPROC ENDP

END main
```

Comment: You have `end start` at `L1`. No idea what you wanted to do there, you should probably remove it.

Comment: Ok, I removed that, but now I am getting this error on Line 59: error 2004 symbol type conflict  

`mov           ax, @data`

Comment: Please mark line 59 in the question.

Comment: line 59 is `mov ax, @data` first line after `start:`

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the superfluous `end start` [pointed out by commenter Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863592/assembly-language-program-fatal-error-a1010/36894231#comment61296299_36863592), it looks to me like you are trying to compile 16-bit assembly using a 32-bit assembler, which won't work. (In conjunction with this, I guess the included file at the beginning should also be `Irvine16.inc` instead of `Irvine32.inc`.)

You have to use a 16-bit assembler project, see http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2015/index.htm#16-bit

However, if you have a 64-bit version of Windows, you won't be able to run your program natively. You would need to use a virtual machine or [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) to run and test your program.

Comment: The only effective address is `[esi]`, so I'm not sure it's 16bit code.  I didn't waste my time really trying to read that giant double-spaced DOS code dump, though.  Oh, now I see the comments about segment crap, yeah maybe some of this did come from a 16bit example.

Comment: OK you are right, it appears to be a weird mix of things, because there is the failing line and the stuff with segment registers, `int 21h` calls as well as the excessive usage of registers smaller than 32 bit but then also `esi`...

Comment: Using 8bit regs is not too bad, esp. if you don't read a wider reg after writing a partial reg.  I just noticed `LEA      DX, MSG`, though.  You're right, that's a huge red flag and only viable in 16bit.  Does `int 21h` work in 32bit mode?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_Protected_Mode_Interface Seems to say it does.  So glad I never had to deal with DOS :)